# How to use the css height attribute for showing scroll bar in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to show scroll bar for a table. I have added a div element around the table with style="height:200px;overFlow:auto;". This is working fine if there are more records in the table, but if there is only one record in the table, i am not able to see the scroll(this is fine) and height of the table is same as before with empty space at bottom(as height i had set to 200px). How can i make the table height to normal by removing the empty space in case of only one record and showing scroll in case of more records.

Comment: Do i need to do anything with height property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a height of 200px on the div, try a max-height of 200px;

```
<div style="max-height:200px;overflow:auto;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d42CA/